# Do the reduce tasks start after all the map tasks have finished?

Tags: mapreduce

e.g. for the sorting example. it the documents are:

`d1 a b c d  -> M1`

`d2 c f k  -> M2`

`d3 c f f  -> M3`

`d4 a b d d  -> M4`
and each document goes to one map task then if (lets only talk about "a") M1 2 and 3 finish first and reduce starts it will not have knowledge of a from d4.

What will happen then? When M4 finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reducer processes will (generally) start up before the mappers finish, but the actual `reduce()` calls will not happen until all the mappers have finished and the intermediate records have been sent to the reducers.